# Apps Script. How to find the time difference between two dates (day, hour, minute)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I think the task is very primitive. But I can't handle it.
I work online (Excel app).
I have cells with time data (dd.mm.yyyy)
Task "I need to find out the time difference between the current date and the time value in the cell)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41p2u.png)

I want to use the current time (const start = Date.now()) and the time in the cell (on the selected sheet)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnZ61.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make sure you've done enough research and show what you tried in your question. See: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/)

Comment: Consider also converting some of your screenshots of code to text. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/)

Answer (score 0):

**The Error in Your Code :** In "01.07.2023" , Date( ) is Treating input as **MM-DD-YYYY** ;

```js
// After getting sheet.getRandge(*).getValue();
cellDate="01.07.2023" 

const [day, month, year] = cellDate.split(".");
const specificDate = new Date(`${year}-${month}-${day}`);

const differenceInDays=Math.abs(Date.now()-specificDate)/86400000; 
//1 day=  60 * 60 * 24 seconds =86400 seconds= 86400*1000 Milliseconds

console.log("The Difference - ",parseInt(differenceInDays), " day")
console.log("//If you want float ",differenceInDays, " in days")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function timeDiff1(Start,End) {
  if(Start && End) {
    var second=1000;
    var minute=60*second;
    var hour=minute*60;
    var day=hour*24;
    var t1=new Date(Start).valueOf();
    var t2=new Date(End).valueOf();
    var d=t2-t1;
    var days=Math.floor(d/day);
    var hours=Math.floor(d%day/hour);
    var minutes=Math.floor(d%day%hour/minute);
    var seconds=Math.floor(d%day%hour%minute/second);
    return 'dd:hh:mm:ss\n' + days + ':' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;  
    //return d/day;
    //return hours + minutes/60;
  }
  else
  {
    return 'Invalid Inputs';
  }
}
```